# How to create new page by clicking on one element from my table?

Tags: html, onclick, href

I have a problem to create command in HTML. What I want is to by click on any element in my table crate a new page where I will show details about that element. Thanks in advance.

Comment: a modal pop up you mean ? have you tried to google it before posting this question ?

Comment: Yes I tried, I found what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, I think what you are looking for is called context menu.

Here is an example of what I am talking about:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contextmenu.asp

In HTML, it seems to have only limited browser support, only firefox from the looks of it.

If you choose to program it with jquery, it seems to have more browser support. Here is a link:
http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html